# Enable user interaction on overlay view

Tags: swift

I'm creating an darken overlay on top of my UITableView, I would like to highlight one of the row. I'm able to highlight it, but how can I enable user interaction (e.g. tap on the cell)?

```
func addFullScreenDarkOverlay(){
    let viewDarkOverlay = UIView()
    viewDarkOverlay.alpha = 0.5
    viewDarkOverlay.backgroundColor = .black
    viewDarkOverlay.frame = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.frame

    //  add dummy hole (will change it to the frame of the particular cell)
    let holeFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewDarkOverlay.frame.width/2, height: viewDarkOverlay.frame.height/2)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    // Dark background
    path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewDarkOverlay.frame.width, height: viewDarkOverlay.frame.height))
    // White/spotlight path
    path.addRect(holeFrame)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    maskLayer.path = path;
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

    viewDarkOverlay.layer.mask = maskLayer
    viewDarkOverlay.clipsToBounds = true


    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(viewDarkOverlay)


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664379/how-to-add-a-transparent-mask-on-map-view

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can disable the user interaction of the mask view, that will pass the all the touch events to the view below... however, if you just want the highlighted area to be intractable (i.e. the cell), you can create a custom UIView subclass, override the `hitTest` method, like so:

```
import UIKit

class MaskView: UIView {

    var hitableArea: CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width * 0.5, height: bounds.height * 0.5)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        installMaskLayer()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        installMaskLayer()
    }

    private func installMaskLayer() {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        // Dark background
        path.addRect(bounds)
        // White/spotlight path
        path.addRect(hitableArea)

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        maskLayer.path = path;
        maskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd

        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if (!self.isUserInteractionEnabled || self.isHidden || self.alpha <= 0.01) {
            return nil;
        }

        if (hitableArea.contains(point)) {
            return nil
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

Just create this custom view and add it to your window, and now you can only touch the cell now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the user interaction in your overlay view and you will be able to select the rows in the view below it:

```
viewDarkOverlay.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

If you want the selection only inside the whole you can transfer the touch from the overlay view to your parent view using a delegate like so:

```
protocol OverlaySelection: class{
    func selected(with touch: UITouch?)
}

class OverlayView: UIView{
    weak var delegate : OverlaySelection?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        delegate?.selected(with: touches.first)
    }
}
```

then in your parent view:

```
func addFullScreenDarkOverlay(){
     let viewDarkOverlay = OverlayView()
     viewDarkOverlay.delegate = self
    //other config..
 }

 //Delegate
func selected(with touch: UITouch?) {
   if let location = touch?.location(in: self.view){
 //Here you check if this point is inside the whole and if it is you select 
 //the row, if not just return
  let indexpath = tableview.indexPathForRow(at: location)
  tableview.selectRow(at: indexpath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... This will allow user interaction in the whole view. How can I only enable it for the current hole?